# Exporting .wav files with Korg Krome Workstation

Tags: software, synthesizer

In SEQ mode of the Korg Krome I want to export my recorded tracks to my SD card. Unfortunately they come out as some weird file type (after I plug my SD into my computer). How can I export as a usable file type like .wav or .mp3

Thanks!

Comment: What type of file do they come out as?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic- it would be better on avp stack exchange